# how can you search cells in row for 10 columns to confirm that they all have a green format

Tags: excel

how can you search cells in row for 10 columns to confirm that they all have a green format, if true change the format colour. I would like to do this search for every row ie from I5:V1947. I am using Excel 2016.

Comment: Color is not data. What have you tried? Do you use VBA?

Comment: Hi, my data is formatted to indicate whether values in each cell are either greater or less than zero ( ie [Blue]#,##0.00;[Red]-#,##0.00), and I selected all cells from I5:V1947, and used conditional formatting to highlight cells > 0 with a light green format. What I would like to know next is how to then search and sort  all the cells for each row, for the ten columns , ie for the range above, have ten green coloured cells (for the ten columns), down to one green coloured cell. I hope this explains what I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper column with a Countif formula that counts the values greater than x, then sort the data by that column.